# How to change elements of ArrayList in It's duplicate without affecting the original one?

Tags: java, android

I have an `ArrayList` of String, let's say `originalArrayList` with some values

```
 final ArrayList<String> originalArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
            originalArrayList.add("value1");
            originalArrayList.add("value2");
            originalArrayList.add("value3");
            originalArrayList.add("value4");
            originalArrayList.add("value5");
```

I copied this `originalArrayList` within inner class and removed some elements

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ArrayList<String> tempArrayList = originalArrayList;
                                
                tempArrayList.remove(0); //Remove an element
               
            }
        });
```

But this is affecting the original `ArrayList` which is `originalArrayList` in my case.

How can I prevent this from happening ?

Comment: clone it https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#clone()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I know simply there are two ways to solve your issue,

- Create new `ArrayList` and add each element of `originalArrayList` using loop (*Not recommended, Because of unncessesory memory consuming task*)
- Clone the `originalArrayList` to `tempArrayList`.

**Adding each element in new ArrayList looks something like this**

```
    ArrayList<String> tempArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String temp : originalArrayList) {
          tempArrayList.add(temp);
      }
```

**Cloning the `ArrayList` looks like this which I will recommend**

```
ArrayList<String> tempArrayList = (ArrayList<String>) originalArrayList.clone();
```

Answer (score 1):

What's happening on the assign statement is a shallow copy, which means two variables point to the same memory location, hence both of them gets changed.

What you can do is clone the `ArrayList` to create a new instance of the `ArrayList`:

`ArrayList<String> tempArrayList = (ArrayList<String>) originalArrayList .clone();`

Answer (score 1):

`ArrayList` offers a constructor that copies any `Collection` passed in.

```
ArrayList<String> tempArrayList = new ArrayList<String>(originalArrayList);
```